# Mouseover is not working in card with dropdown or datepicker or timepicker etc

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

- I have a card which is having a date-picker, drop-down and simple
  input field
- I have added mouse over to each card. when we mouse over the card get
  highlighted(this means if mouse is within the card, the background
  color should be highlighted).
- When i click on date-picker or drop-down the card background color change
  back to white.
  I have added the code to stackblitz link is below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bu4fcp-kjwacf

[image: this is how it should look when mouseover inside the card]

[image: In this image we can see that when we click on datepicker the background color change back to white(even though it is inside the card)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick Fix :

Try removing mouseout attribute from date-picker card.

```
(mouseout)="cardNumber=0"
```

#### Updated code :

```
<mat-card (click)="activateThisCard(1)" [ngClass]="{'selected': cardNumber == 1}" (mouseover)="cardNumber=1">
```

#### Screenshot :

[image]